# How to hide certain Objective-C method header documentation (HeaderDoc) comments

Tags: objective-c, code-documentation, headerdoc

Is there a way in Objective-C documentation (HeaderDoc) to hide certain comments from being visible to the public?

In other words, when you option-click (alt-click) on a method you're calling, that box pops up showing the comments for that method...I want a certain comment on the method to not show up in that box.

Here's my scenario:

```
/**
 * This method does something.
 * 
 * For more info on why NS_SWIFT_NAME is specified on this, see: <link here>
 */
- (void)doSomething NS_SWIFT_NAME(doSomething())
```

Now, when someone uses `doSomthing()` in Swift and looks at the documentation popup box, the comment about `NS_SWIFT_NAME` makes no sense to them (it has no useful API information for them on how the method works or how to use it). So, I don't want that comment to show up.

However, if someone were to look at the actual method and see `NS_SWIFT_NAME` on there, I want them to be able to know why it's there. And I don't want to pull the comment outside of the documentation block and make it a `//` code comment because I think that would be pretty ugly.

Are there any keywords that let you hide certain comments in the header docs? Like `@hide` or something?